# To return ordered criteria.list()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have `PlayerEntity` hibernate entity corresponds to the table

```
  id       date       amount
serial   timestamp    integer
```

Suppose I have a `List<Date> lst`. I need to execute query that returns all `PlayerEntity` elements which is in `lst` and ordered by the `lst`'s order. I mean, the first element, returned by `criteria.list()` shall be an element which is corresponded to the `lst.get(0)`  date, the second shall be corresponded to the `lst.get(1)` date, etcetera. If I simply write

```
criteria.add(restriction.in("date", lst));
List<PlayerEntity> players = criteria.list();
```

I won't receive an ordered List of players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a 'great' way of doing this. I think you'd need to iterate over the 'lst', find a match in 'player' and build a new list as you go.

I'm a little confused though - is the 'date' in the PlayerEntity table? If so, you can just do:

```
criteria.add(Order.desc("date"));
```

Comment: You mean I have to execute `lst.size()` times `criteria.list()` to do that, don't you?

Comment: Yes, if the lists are separate, I don't think there's a way to get away from that.

Comment: Alternatively, if your list of dates is in the database, you could use the DB to join them - that would be more efficient.

Comment: The thing is I have to use hibernate, but not native sql.

Comment: What about HQL? And I'm still not sure whether your date list is the same one as the one in PlayerEntity?

Comment: Well, lst is a List of dates the `PlayerEntity`'s date field shall belong to. It would be good if it possible to do with HQL...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60537/discussion-between-daniel-scott-and-st-antario).

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria list contains the dates in ascending or descending order, then ordering is simple:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("timestamp")) // or Order.desc
```

Otherwise you need to sort the items in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PlayerEntity.class);
criteria.setOrder(Order.DESC("date"));
List<Player> players = criteria.list();
for(Player player : players){
    // process the logic
}
```